# $\mu^{\ast}(\alpha A) = |\alpha|^2 \mu^{\ast}(A)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove that this statement in real analysis:

If $A \subset R^2$ is measurable, then $\alpha A$ is measurable and

$$\mu^{\ast}(\alpha A) = |\alpha|^2 \mu^{\ast}(A)$$

Thanks for your help and time.

My idea is this:

$$
m^*(E)=\inf\left\{\sum_{n≥1}\ell (I_n)\middle|E\subset\cup_{n≥1}I_n\right\}
$$
and we note that $m(E)=m^*(E)$ for measurable sets $E$.

Noe note that any set $A\subseteq(a,b)$ satisfies $\alpha A\subseteq(\alpha a,\alpha b)$ and that $\ell(\alpha(a,b))=\alpha \, \ell(a,b)$.  It follows that for any collection of sets $\{I_n\}_{n≥1}$ whose union contains $E$, we may state that $\{\alpha I_n\}_{n≥1}$ is a collection whose union contains $\alpha E$ and whose total length is $\alpha$ times longer.  For any set $A$ of real numbers, $\inf (\alpha A) = \alpha \inf A$.  The desired statement follows.

Is this correct?

Comment: If $\mu$ is $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, your scaling is wrong.

Comment: did you try to prove anything? Did you consider the case when $A\subset R$ (instead of $R^2$), since for $R$ the above equality would hold? For the plane, first consider the case when $A$ is a (filled in) square, to come up with the correct scaling.

Comment: well this is the first problem in the section in fact I don't understand at all the theory os measure, this is the reason why I ask this first problem.

Comment: Did you start reading the problems at the end of the section without reading the section itself? Do you expect someone would be able to explain the whole theory of measure in an answer here? Perhaps, if you know some theory of measure, one could try to explain the answer to the specific question posted above ... or more likely you would be able to answer it easily yourself? (Think of measure in the plane as area, if that is easier to understand.)

Comment: It needs to be $|\alpha|^2$. Think of a square.

Comment: considering the proof in general, I don't know what would be best, but I am thinking of covering $A$ with squares that do not overlap except at the edges. If you use this approach, you would need to prove that it indeed defines $\mu^*(A)$, but (1) I don't know what approach your book uses, and (2) I do not know if there might perhaps be something easier. (Or the squares may overlap, that should be ok, even if the interiors overlap.)

Comment: im using Kolmogorov-Fomin book Introductory real analysis.

Comment: I have seen this book years ago ... do not have it in front of me. I do not know what their definition of $\mu^*$ is, but I think as a step toward the solution one might show that using covers of $A$ consisting of squares would also result in defining $\mu^*$ in an equivalent way.

Comment: $\mu^{\ast}(\alpha A) = inf_{A \subset \cup_k P_k} \sum_{k} m(P_k)$ where the greatest lower bound is taken over all coverings of A by aJinite
or countable system of rectangles $P_k$

Comment: @Mirko I edited my answer. Can you see it? please.

Comment: If $\ell(\alpha(a,b))=\alpha \, \ell(a,b)$ then probably $\ell$ is length, and you are considering $R$, not $R^2$, and your original version with $|\alpha|$ would be correct, instead of $|\alpha|^2$ ?

Comment: The problem is in $R^2$ but you suggested me try it first in $R$

Comment: for the plane it would be similar, as I see that they use elementary rectangles in their definition. Note that if a rectangle $T$ has sides $p$ and $q$, and hence area $p\cdot q$ then the rectangle $\alpha T$ would have sides $|\alpha|p$ and $|\alpha|q$, and hence area $|\alpha|p\cdot|\alpha|q=|\alpha|^2p\cdot q$.

Answer (score -1):

Use the uniqueness of the Lebesgue measure.  The Lebesgue measure $\mu$ on $\mathbf R^n$ is the unique measure on the Borel sets of $\mathbf R^n$ satisfying the following properties:

> 1 .  $\mu(E + x) = \mu(E)$ for all Borel sets $E$ and all $x \in \mathbf R^n$.
>
> 2 .  Every Borel set can be measured from within by compact sets, and measured from without by open sets.
>
> 3 .  $\mu( [0,1] \times \cdots \times [0,1]) = 1$.

Comment: sounds a bit too vague ... one might as well suggest to use that 2+2=4

Comment: It's not so vague.  If $\phi$ is the linear transformation $\mathbf R^2 \rightarrow \mathbf R^2$ given by $\phi(v)  = cv$, all you have to do is show that $\mu \circ \phi$ is a measure satisfying the first two properties.  Then $$\frac{1}{c^2} \mu \circ \phi([0,1] \times [0,1]) = \frac{1}{c^2} \mu([0,c] \times [0,c]) = 1$$
so $\frac{1}{c^2} \mu \circ \phi = \mu$ by uniqueness.  So $\mu(cE) = c^2 \mu(E)$ when $c > 0$, $E$ Borel.